# Can't get a handleClick function to call other functions as opposed to doing itself the work they do

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, onclicklistener

I can't get the mouse coordinates like this

```
function handleClick() {
    getMouseCoordinates();
    calculateDistance();
    handleRotation();
    document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = mouseX;
}

function getMouseCoordinates(e) {
    var offset = $('#gameWrapper').offset();
    mouseX = Math.round(e.clientX - offset.left);
    mouseY = Math.round(e.clientY - offset.top);
}
```

But this way it works

```
function handleClick(e) {
    var offset = $('#gameWrapper').offset();
    mouseX = Math.round(e.clientX - offset.left);
    mouseY = Math.round(e.clientY - offset.top);
    calculateDistance();
    handleRotation();
    document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = mouseX;
}
```

The first way seems a better way to do it I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the event object into any of your functions that need it:

```
function handleClick(e) {
// ------------------^
    getMouseCoordinates(e);
// ---------------------^
    calculateDistance(); // If these need it, pass it...
    handleRotation();    // ...to them as well
    document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = mouseX;
}
```

If you need information back from any of those (such as `mouseX`), make that information a return value from the function, and then save it in a local variable (or use it directly).